# Line of text breaks when it doesn't fit on page - HTML to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, coldfusion

I have the following issue. I am working on a HTML PDF in Coldfusion but everytime when a line of text doesn't fit well on the first page it will be cut of half and continues on the next page (see image).

The content on the page will be different every time it is generated because it is an automatic generated personal data resume (c.v.).

I've tried the following CSS properties but they all didn't work for me:

```
page-break-after  : auto | always | avoid | left | right
page-break-before : auto | always | avoid | left | right
page-break-inside : auto | avoid
```

[image: Image - Line of text breaks in two]

---

Anyone ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your code? Only this much information is not enough to find the issue.

Comment: CSS properties wont be much help in this case.